# Write a program to input a line of text and create a new line of text where each word of input line is reversed

Tags: python

This question is in my book and when I tried to make it in python, the program is showing error.

```
a=input("Enter the line: ")

W=''

s=a.split()

for i in s:

    q=len(i)

    for b in range(q-1,-1,-1):

        w=w+b+' '

print(w)
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Good places to start are the [tour] and [ask]. When looking for help troubleshooting code, make sure you include a full [MRE]—including what exact behavior you're observing. If you get an error, please post the full stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you were trying to do with that loop, but I'd split the line by space, reverse every word using a slice (`[::-1]`) and join them back together:

```py
text = input("Enter the line: ")
result = ' '.join(word[::-1] for word in text.split(' '))
print(result)
```

Comment: It is showing : 'Future' object has no attribute 'split'. i.e. attribute error.

Comment: @AkshatParmar do you have anything else in your program? This snippet should work just fine: https://onlinegdb.com/4f73ugzgP

Comment: I am using jupiter notebook maybe it has something to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

Disregarding the purpose of this code, you have a couple of errors:

- Python is case sensitive, you initialized a var called `W` at the start but then started to use `w` in the rest of the code
- `w=w+b+' '` will throw an error since `b` is an int, cast it to string `w=w+str(b)+' '`

Comment: Even after fixing the errors it is showing: 'Future' object has no attribute 'split'.

Comment: @AkshatParmar what environment are you using? because `input()` should wait for you to input the text on runtime.

Comment: I am leaving this question. Nothing's working
Thanks for helping btw.

Comment: That's a problem with Jupyter. The workaround is to [`await input()` or use a different kernel](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/codes-on-https-jupyter-org-try-jupyter-lab-not-working-properly-anymore/13374/2).